# How to fetch all subreddits PRAW/PSAW

Tags: python, reddit, praw

Hi I have a program where i want to loop through all subreddits:

```
for subreddit in reddit.subreddits.default(limit=None):
```

The code above however only fetches around about the top 100 subreddits.

PSAW seems to only support comments and submissions so how can I loop through all subreddits and feed them into PRAW?

Thanks

Comment: Are you  sure there are more 'default' subreddits? I don't think so.

Comment: A submission in [r/defaults](https://www.reddit.com/r/defaults/comments/61mgs9/list_of_default_subreddits_26_march_2017/) gave a list of only 47 subreddits as of 2017.

Comment: What would i use to get all subreddits?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether PRAW gives you this service. If you're happy with a list of 5000 subs then go for [this](http://redditlist.com/all) or else to get complete list check [this](https://www.reddit.com/reddits). Either way you have to scrap on your own, although I don't think it's legal.

Comment: Not a lawyer, but as far as I am aware of, web scraping is fine in most countries as long as the content is publicly accessible.

Answer (score 1):

praw does not provide a way to get a list of all subreddits. You can download and read from the .csv files provided [Here](https://redditmetrics.com/list-all-subreddits). You can see as of 11 October 2019 there are over 1.68 million subreddits. The [person who created that website](https://old.reddit.com/r/ListOfSubreddits/comments/d7ze8e/regularly_updated_complete_list_of_current/) says they update the files on a weekly basis.

Comment: Interesting! So the official reddit api doesn't provide one to fetch all the available subreddits?

Answer (score 0):

.default() only gives you default subreddits

The [PRAW docs](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/reddit/subreddits.html) show the different search options available for subreddits.

If you're set on going this route I imagine you could use .search_by_name() in a for loop where each search starts with a different letter. But keep in mind you're limited to 1000 results per loop this method.